# Can you create a "simulated printer" in OS X/Linux?

Tags: linux, macos, unix, printing, language-agnostic

I'm learning Rust, and as a project I want to create a binding crate for libcups.  I also want to create a simple GUI with print functionality.

As such, I will need to be printing a lot for test purposes.  The problem is, I don't have a printer!

Is there a piece of software for *nix systems that'll appear as a printer on my machine, but will only display the document + diagnostic information when I print to it?

I'd like to test both "physical" and "network" printers if possible.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you "print" to PDF? For Linux I think there's a way to get Ghostscript to show up as an output option.

Comment: The OS X Print dialog allows you to save as PDF.